# How to TOUCH DRAW Shapes on the HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, touch, draw, shapes

I have a question...

I'm trying to figure out how to **touch draw** shapes on an HTML5 canvas. I've been searching everywhere and so far it's been impossible to find any descent **tutorial** on matter. Can somebody please help me out? I know how to "draw" shapes on the canvas (with code), but how do you **draw/paint** with (**touch**) your finger for **mobile apps**?

Here's my code so far...

Javascript:

---

```
        // draws a Square to the x and y coordinates of the mouse event inside
  // the specified element using the specified context
  function drawSquare(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {

     var position = getPosition(mouseEvent, sigCanvas);

     context.strokeStyle = "color";
     context.strokeRect(x,y,width,height);
  }

  // draws a square from the last coordiantes in the path to the finishing
  // coordinates and unbind any event handlers which need to be preceded
  // by the mouse down event
  function finishDrawing(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context) {
     // draw the line to the finishing coordinates
     drawSquare(mouseEvent, sigCanvas, context);

     context.closePath();

     // unbind any events which could draw
     $(sigCanvas).unbind("mousemove")
                 .unbind("mouseup")
                 .unbind("mouseout");
  }
```

HTML5:

---

```
    <div id="squareButton">  
    <p><button onclick="drawSquare();">Square</button></p>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot,
Wardenclyffe

Answer (score 2):

Not really a tutorial, but MDN has a solution here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events#Drawing_as_the_touches_move

additionally you might want to look into the touch events ( also available on the same link above )

here is an excerpt from the link I provided

```
function startup() {
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchleave", handleEnd, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
}
```

Comment: It seems like my html5 button is having effect on the JS code. Whenever I click on the canvas a square automatically pops up instead of first allowing me the option to click on my "Square" button and then draw it.

Comment: I think you need to rethink what you are trying to accomplish, you need to get rid of the click event, and add the new touch events, if you want to do is being able to draw with your touch events instead of the click drawing a box